# SwipeRefreshLayout with WebView in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, webview, android-toolbar, swiperefreshlayout, coordinator-layout

This is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/tool_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Unfortunately, the toolbar is not hiding when webView scrolling.

How do I use a WebView with SwipeRefreshLayout and hideable toolbar?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 11):

Use [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: i not use CoordinatorLayout but NestedScrollView help me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! you save my day!

Comment: This is great, also solved my problem with scrolling up triggering an unwanted refresh action